# Clustering mixed data

Tags: machine-learning, r, clustering

I have 90000 records for customer segmentation consisting of numeric nominal and ordinal variables:

```
*houselhold_ID* ID for household

*quantity*: integer, number of products bought

*price*: values 1 to 3 with 1 for 0-5, 2 for 5-8 and 3 for 8-10

*product name*: nominal values 1 to 9 representing 9 different products like different kind of cheese...

*duration*: days from the current buy to the next buy.

*age*: catgeorical age groups: 1: 0-24 years, 2: 25-39 years, 3: 40-59 etc.

*salary*: 1: to 1499 2 : 1500 bis 2499 3 : 2500 bis 3499 4 : 3500 or more 

*number_of_persons_household*: integer 

*price_con*: price conscious: 1 to 4 for not price conscious 
to very price conscious

*education*: 1 to 3 for lower education to high school/university.
```

I already did outliers detection and removed them having small frequencies. Most household have 40 buys.

I want to cluster analysis in R for to find patterns in this data.

I currently run kmodes and and want to test kproto too.

But my question:

is there any possibility to things do like Hopkin statistics for clusterness like with numeric values?

Is there also a kind of visualization if I have more than 2 classes? So that one can visualize the data points in to groups.

Maybe someone has experience with such kind of data. I am open for hints and tips to analyse this data.

EDIT:

Here is the elbow plot for kmodes with 15 iterations and 20000 records from the full 90000:
[image]

So 2 or 3 clusters are good?

EDIT2:

I did now a Multi Factor Analysis in R. Additionally I did some engineering for the duration variable. I categorized the variable in three groups splitted according to the mean and quantiles in low, mid, high duration.

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
    res.mfa <- MFA(dat[1:20000,], 
                   group = c(1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                   type = c("c", "n", "n", "n", "n","c","n","n","n"),
                   name.group = c("quantity","price","product",
                                  "age","salary","persn","price_con","edu", "duration"),

                   graph = FALSE)
```

I used a group for each variable.
The result seem poor. Only 30% of variance can be explained with 6 dimensions?! So bad?

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69079/discussion-on-question-by-tradphy-clustering-mixed-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try HAC with Gower's similarity.

It is a very heuristic approach - there is nothing going to save you from weighting variables - but worth a try.

Comment: Does the NBClust function has no option for gower distance etc.?

Comment: If I use daisy for hclust, ithas problems with only 20000 records with memory. Is there a better option?

Comment: It is not possible to work with other cluster techniques besides kmodes. Or is there a better distance mesaure then daisy? dist() doesnt have gower. daisy() has problems somehow with my memory allocation.

Comment: Well, first figure out if it *works* on a sample, then think about scaling. If it doesn't work (e.g., because your similarity does not work) then there is no use in scaling. No O(n^2) memory method will scale well.

Comment: It is not easy to find the rfunctions for categorical data (everything seem only for continous variables). For example I am interested to use get_clust_tendency from factorextra# or NBClust for determining optimal number of clusters using gower distance eg.

Comment: There is "optimal" number of clusters. These are just heuristics. There also is no optimal distance function, it needs to *carefully* be adapted to the problem.